# Can a Windows XP client connect to a RemoteApp hosted on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

Can a Windows XP client (running SP3 if that matters) connect to a RemoteApp hosted on a Server 2008 R2 RDSH server?

I've searched the Internet for an answer but keep finding information explaining how to configure an XP client to *host* a RemoteApp, which is the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows XP SP2 and higher can access RemoteApps.** According to the Microsoft TechNet page [Distribute RemoteApp Programs to Users](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730603.aspx):

> To access RemoteApp programs, the client computer must be running at least Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) 6.0.

If you have at least Windows XP SP2, the minimum RDC client version is already included in the operating system.  Newer clients are also available:

- RDC v6.0 was first made [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Version_6.0) for Windows XP SP2.
- RDC v6.1 was [included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Version_6.1) with Windows XP SP3.
- RDC v7.0 is available as a [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969084) from Microsoft for Windows XP SP3